# SQL Regex substr function in amazon redshift

Tags: sql, regex, amazon-redshift

In my database, there is a table which shows the landing pages, and what I want to do is to classify if the traffic is from SEO channel. When the landing page is exactly equal to the pattern /countrycode/index.aspx, then it should be regarded as 'SEO', otherwise mark it as 'non-SEO'.

The table should be something like this

```
    landing_page                               channel 
   /en/index.aspx                               SEO 
   /de/index.aspx                               SEO 
   /es/features/mobile-apps/index.aspx         Non-SEO 
   /ja/products/product01123                   Non-SEO
```

To do this, I write a regex exression in Redshift like

```
   SELECT 
      landing_page, 
      CASE 
        WHEN 
          regexp_substr(landing_page, '/\/[a-z]{2,4}\/index.aspx')  IS NULL
        THEN 'Non-SEO' ELSE 'SEO'
      END channel 
   FROM 
      marketing_table
```

I tested in the regextester, it works prefect for me. However, when I apply it into Redshift, the outcome is simply as follows

```
    landing_page                               channel 
   /en/index.aspx                               SEO 
   /de/index.aspx                               SEO 
   /es/features/mobile-apps/index.aspx          SEO 
   /ja/products/product01123                    SEO
   /download/testing                           NON-SEO
```

That means, all the strings that between the / and /index.aspx are all considered, and what I need is the exact match. Is there any suggestion that I can fix it?

Many thanks for your help!

Update: Sorry guys for the late update. The problem is still not yet solved. The most confusing point is, For the same landing page in different traffic, some of them is regarded as SEO and some of them are not e.g

```
        landing_page                               channel 
   /en/index.aspx                               SEO 
   /en/index.aspx                               Non-SEO
```

We tried different method e.g not using regex but length of the string for example len(landing_page) in (12,13,14,15,16). Does anyone have any idea for that?

Comment: Did my answer help? Note that you should really use `$` to mastch end of string and `^` to match start of string.

Answer (score 1):

You should use

```
'/[a-z]{2,4}/index[.]aspx'
```

Here, the `/` is removed from the start and `[.]` is used to match a *literal* dot. Since the regex in Amazon Redshift does not use regex delimiters, you do not need to "wrap" the whole pattern with `/` chars and you do not need to escape `/` since they are not special regex metachars.

Answer (score 1):

The answer above me by @Wiktor-Stribiżew is almost right. he is missing the start and end-of-line characters.
consider the following case with the input URL:

```
/es/features/en/index.aspx
```

according to the OP, this should not be classified as SEO. but with the the regexp `'/[a-z]{2,4}/index[.]aspx'` it will be. the correct regexp to use is `'^/[a-z]{2,4}/index[.]aspx$'`

```
select regexp_substr('/es/features/en/index.aspx','/[a-z]{2,4}/index[.]aspx');
>>> /en/index.aspx
select regexp_substr('/es/features/en/index.aspx','^/[a-z]{2,4}/index[.]aspx$');
>>> null
select regexp_substr('/en/index.aspx','^/[a-z]{2,4}/index[.]aspx$');
>>> /en/index.aspx
select regexp_substr('/es/features/mobile-apps/index.aspx','^/[a-z]{2,4}/index[.]aspx$')
>>> null
```